# SQL Show most recent record in GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id    |    SubjectCode    |    Grade    |    DateApproved    |    StudentId

1            SUB123            1.25            1/4/2012            2012-12345

2            SUB123            2.00            1/5/2012            2012-12345

3            SUB123            3.00            1/5/2012            2012-98765
```

I'm trying to GROUP BY SubjectCode but i'd like it to display the most recent DateApproved so it will look like:

```
  id    |    SubjectCode    |    Grade    |    DateApproved    |    StudentId

2            SUB123            2.00            1/5/2012            2012-12345

3            SUB123            3.00            1/5/2012            2012-98765
```

I'm a little bit lost on how to do it?

EDIT:

Ok guys now im on my real PC, sorry for the poorly constructed question.

Here's what I'm actually trying to do:

```
SELECT GD.GradebookDetailId, G.SubjectCode, G.Description, G.UnitsAcademic, G.UnitsNonAcademic, 
GD.Grade, GD.Remarks, G.FacultyName, STR_TO_DATE(G.DateApproved, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s') AS 'DateAproved'
FROM gradebookdetail GD INNER JOIN gradebook G ON GD.GradebookId=G.GradebookId 
WHERE G.DateApproved IS NOT NULL AND G.GradebookType='final' AND StudentIdNumber='2012-12345'

GROUP BY <?????>
ORDER BY G.SubjectCode ASC
```

Basically, I only want to display the **most recent** "DateApprove" of a "SubjectCode", so I don't get multiple entries.

Comment: You actually want to group by StudentId. The way to do this is to select max(DateApproved). (Assuming that DateApproved is a date field)

Comment: Ok, DateApproved is a VARCHAR, will this work: MAX(STR_TO_DATE(DateApproved, '%d%m%y')) ?

Comment: Hmm. It's worth a shot I suppose. You'll have to try it and see. Am not too familiar with mysql syntax.

Comment: First, fix your date columns, by making the of `DATE` datatype. Why on earth are you using `VARCHAR` for dates?

Comment: @ypercube, I don't have modify privilleges

Answer (score 39):

Start with this:

```
select StudentId, max(DateApproved) 
from tbl
group by StudentId
```

Then integrate that to main query:

```
select * 
from tbl
where (StudentId, DateApproved) in

(
  select StudentId, max(DateApproved) 
  from tbl
  group by StudentId
)
```

You can also use this:

```
select * 
from tbl
join (select StudentId, max(DateApproved) as DateApproved 
      from tbl 
      group by StudentId)
using (StudentId, DateApproved)
```

But I prefer tuple testing, it's way [neater](http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/05/tuple-matching-is-neat-how-to-simulate.html)

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/771b8/5

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM temp t2 
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT MAX(DateApproved) as MaxDate, StudentId
    FROM temp
    GROUP BY StudentId
    ) t1 ON t1.MaxDate = t2.DateApproved and t1.StudentId = t2.StudentId
```

Comment: H eprobably needs `GROUP BY StudentId, SubjectCode` (and appropriately changed `ON` condition). But this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

For users trying this in SQL Server, which at the time of this writing (2020) still does not support tuples, then you can use the following (improving upon  another answer here)

Change this:

```
-- MYSQL
select * 
from tbl
where (StudentId, DateApproved) in
(
  select StudentId, max(DateApproved) 
  from tbl
  group by StudentId
)
```

into this:

```
-- Microsoft SQL Server
select * 
from tbl
where concat(StudentId, DateApproved) in
(
  select concat(StudentId, max(DateApproved)) 
  from tbl
  group by StudentId
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TheTable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM TheTable b
                 WHERE b.StudentCode = a.StudentCode AND b.DateApproved > a.DateApproved)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was more efficient for me in postgres.

```
select * from tbl t1 where t1.DateApproved = (select max(t2.DateApproved) from tbl t2 where t2.StudentId = t1.StudentId)
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works for SQL Server 2016.

select StudentId,
max(DateApproved)
from tbl
group by StudentId

This code will show max and min date approved per student id.

select StudentId,
max(DateApproved),
min(DateApproved)
from tbl
group by StudentId