# optimal django manytomany query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm having trouble reducing the number of queries for a particular view. It's a fairly heavy one but I'm sure it can be reduced:

```
Profile:
  name = CharField()

Officers:
  club= ManyToManyField(Club, related_name='officers')
  title= CharField()

Club:
  name = CharField()
  members = ManyToManyField(Profile)

Election:
    club = ForeignKey(Club)
    elected = ForeignKey(Profile)
    title= CharField()
    when = DateTimeField()
```

Clubs have members and officers (president, tournament director). People can be members of multiple clubs etc...
Officers are elected at elections, the results of which are stored.

Given a player how can I find out the most recently elected officer at each of the players clubs?

At the moment I have

```
clubs = Club.objects.filter(members=me).prefetch_related('officers')
for c in clubs:
  officers = c.officers.all()

  most_recent = Elections.objects.filter(club=c).filter(elected__in=officers).order_by('-when')[:1].get()
  print(c.name + ' elected ' + most_recent.name + ' most recently')
```

Problem is the looped query, it's nice and fast if you're a member of 1 club but if you join fifty my database crawls.

**Edit:**
The answer from Nil does what I want but doesn't get the object. I don't really need the object but I do need another field as well as the datetime. If it's helpful the query:

```
Club.objects.annotate(last_election=Max('election__when'))
```

produces the raw SQL

```
SELECT "organisation_club"."id", "organisation_club"."name", MAX("organisation_election"."when") AS "last_election" 
    FROM "organisation_club" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "organisation_election" ON ( "organisation_club"."id" = "organisation_election"."club_id" ) 
    GROUP BY "organisation_club"."id", "organisation_club"."name"
```

I'd really like an ORM answer if at all possible (or a 'mostly' ORM answer).

Comment: You probably meant `officer = models.ForeignKey(Officer)`?

Comment: Election is actually an intermediary table for another ManyToMany relationship between Club and Profile. Using django's [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) might help shorten the query (not sure how it would help efficiency)

Comment: I think you example code doesn't work. `most_recent.name` raises an error as `Election` doesn't have a `name` attribute. Also it helps referring to your entities by their model names: I suspect by "Given a player" you mean a "Given a `profile`"?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

Election.objects.filter(club__members=me) \
                .annotate(max_date=Max('club__election_set__when')) \
                .filter(when=F('max_date')).select_related('elected')
```

Relations can be followed forwards and backwards again in a single statement, allowing you to annotate the max_date for any election related to the club of the current election. The `F` class allows you to filter a queryset based on selected fields in SQL, including any extra fields added through annotation, aggregation, joins etc.

Comment: Isn't `Election.objects.filter(club__in=Club.objects.filter(members=me))` the same as `Election.objects.filter(club__members=me)`?

Comment: @Chris They produce the same results with slightly different SQL queries. Updated my answer for readability.

Comment: So the query planner should come op with the same execution plan... in theory... I've had huge success in the past, rephrasing queries so the MySQL planner (they optimistically call it *optimizer*) would come up better execution plans for logically equivalent queries.

Comment: Yep. But apparently `INNER JOIN` (and thus `club__members=me`) is superior in performance over an `IN (subquery)` statement in most cases.

Comment: This seems to work so I'm accepting.
<picky>you're missing a close bracket end of line two</picky>

Answer (score 3):

What you want is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445162/sql-show-most-recent-record-in-group-by) in SQL term: query the `Election` table, group them by `Club` and keep only the last election of each club.

Now, how can we translate that in Django ORM? Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates), we learn that we can do it with an annotation. The trick is that you need to think in reverse. You want to annotate (add a new data) each club with its last election. This gives us:

```
Club.objects.annotate(last_election=Max('election__when'))

# Use it in a for loop like that
for club in Club.objects.annotate(last_election=Max('election__when')):
    print(club, club.last_election)
```

**Sadly, this only adds the date, which doesn't answer your question!** You want the name or the complete `Club` object. I searched and I still don't know how to do it properly. If everything fails though, you can still use a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/) in Django using a query like in the first link.

Comment: Your answer is so frustratingly close to being what I want. It reduces the queries to a constant number and a lower number than I had for a single group! I think I'll have to dive into the sql to get the full information.

Comment: I was also frustrated when I realized that I didn't answer your question! You might consider starting a bounty. It will only cost you 50 points and you may win more :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is filtering partially at the application level

If you do

```
e = Election.objects.filter(club__members=me).select_related('elected')
```

or

```py
e = me.club_set.election_set.select_related('elected')
```

This is a single query and it should get back all the elections that happened for the all the clubs that the member `me` is in. Then you can use python to just get the most recent date. Of course, if you have many elections per club, you end up fetching much more data than will be used.

Another way which should do it in two queries:

```py
# Get all member's clubs & most recent election
clubs = Club.objects.filter(members=me).annotate(last_election=Max('election__when'))
# Create filters for election based on the club id and the latest election time
election_Q = [Q(club__id=c.id) & Q(when=c.last_election) for c in clubs]
# Combine filters with an OR
election_filter = reduce(lambda f1, f2: f1 | f2, election_Q)

# Get elections restricting by specific clubs & election date
elections = Election.objects.filter(election_filter).select_related('elected')

for e in elections:
    print '%s elected %s most recently at %s' % (e.club.name, e.elected, e.when)
```

This builds upon @Nil's method and uses its result to build a query in python, then feeds it into the second query. However, there is a limit with the size of a SQL statement and if there are a lot of clubs that a member is in, then you may hit the limit. The limit is fairly high though and I've only ever reached it when importing large datasets in a single INSERT statement so I think it should be fine for your purpose.

Sorry I cannot think of a way that the Django ORM can link them together using a single SQL query. The Django ORM is actually [quite limited](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/shortcomings-in-the-django-orm-and-a-look-at-peewee-a-lightweight-alternative/) for complex queries so if you really need the efficiency I think it's probably best to write the raw SQL query.