# How to speed up the return of most recent records in group by query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return the most recent records from a `GROUP BY` mysql query.

My data looks like this:

```
id  | user_id | rate_gbp    | active | created_at
===============================================================
1   | 5       | 10.000000   | 1      | 2016-05-19 18:42:55
2   | 6       | 10.000000   | 0      | 2016-05-19 18:42:58
3   | 7       | 10.000000   | 0      | 2016-05-19 18:42:59
4   | 8       | 10.000000   | 0      | 2016-05-19 18:43:01
5   | 9       | 10.000000   | 1      | 2016-05-19 18:43:03
6   | 10      | 10.000000   | 0      | 2016-05-19 18:43:05
7   | 11      | 10.000000   | 0      | 2016-05-19 18:43:07
8   | 12      | 10.000000   | 0      | 2016-05-19 18:43:09
```

Some records were amended multiple times in a single day, and I want to pull only the most recent record per day for each rate.

I've tried to implement a solution like the one here: [SQL Show most recent record in GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445162/sql-show-most-recent-record-in-group-by) which looks like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  user_id,
  date_format(rates.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') AS sday,
  MAX(rates.created_at) AS latest_record
FROM rates
GROUP BY id,
         sday) r1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  *
FROM rates) r2
  ON r2.created_at = rates.latest_record
  AND r2.user_id = rates.user_id
GROUP BY r1.user_id,
         r2.sday
```

This works ok but is slower than I'd like.

I've also used `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT...` however this gives a warning that rows are being cut, and unfortunately I don't have permissions to alter the value of `group_concat_max_len` (it's currently 1024).

Is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide table indexes ?

Comment: running SHOW INDEX FROM rates; shows id, user_id and active as indexes, with id the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Start with adding this index:

```
ALTER TABLE `rates` ADD INDEX `rates_idx_id_id_at` (`id`, `user_id`, `created_at`);
```

Also, extracting the subqueries in the FROM clause to temporary tables, indexing them and then joining should be much quicker than joining to the subqueries, which in many cases are non indexable.

The following should assist you with creating the temp tables, index them and then run the query that joins them:

```
-- Transformed subquery to a temp table to improve performance
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS SELECT
        rates.user_id,
        date_format(rates.created_at,
        '%Y-%m-%d') AS sday,
        MAX(rates.created_at) AS latest_record 
    FROM
        rates 
    GROUP BY
        rates.id,
        sday 
    ORDER BY
        NULL;

-- Transformed subquery to a temp table to improve performance
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp2 AS SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        rates;

-- This index is required for optimal temp tables performance
ALTER TABLE
  `temp1`
ADD
  INDEX `temp1_idx_id` (`user_id`);

-- This index is required for optimal temp tables performance
ALTER TABLE
  `temp2`
ADD
  INDEX `temp2_idx_at_id_sday` (`created_at`, `user_id`, `sday`);

SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        temp1 r1 
    LEFT JOIN
        temp2 r2 
            ON r2.created_at = rates.latest_record 
            AND r2.user_id = rates.user_id 
    GROUP BY
        r1.user_id,
        r2.sday 
    ORDER BY
        NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  select * from table group by created_at,rate_gbp order by created_at desc
```

Comment: This doesn't work - if I include max(created_at) as a field, the results don't match - i.e. max(created_at) != created_at for the returned records.